# Parsing complex JSON into goweb REST Create() function

Tags: json, rest, post, go

I apologise in advance for a *very* long question. Hopefully you'll bear with me.

I'm working with the [goweb](https://github.com/stretchr/goweb) library, and experimenting with the [example web app](https://github.com/stretchr/goweb/blob/master/example_webapp/main.go).

I've been trying to modify the [RESTful example code](https://github.com/stretchr/goweb/blob/master/example_webapp/main.go#L222-L311), which defines a [`Thing`](https://github.com/stretchr/goweb/blob/master/example_webapp/main.go#L226-L230) as:

```
type Thing struct {
    Id   string
    Text string
}
```

A `Thing` is created by sending an `HTTP Post` request, with an appropriate `JSON` body, to `http://localhost:9090/things`. This is handled in the example code in the [`Create` function](https://github.com/stretchr/goweb/blob/master/example_webapp/main.go#L249-L267), specifically the lines:

```
dataMap := data.(map[string]interface{})

thing := new(Thing)
thing.Id = dataMap["Id"].(string)
thing.Text = dataMap["Text"].(string)
```

This is all well and good, and I can run the example server (which listens on `http://localhost:9090/`) and the server operates as expected.

For example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Id":"TestId","Text":"TestText"}' http://localhost:9090/things
```

returns with no error, and then I `GET` that `Thing` with

```
curl http://localhost:9090/things/TestId
```

and it returns

```
{"d":{"Id":"TestId","Text":"TestText"},"s":200}
```

So far, so good.

Now, I would like to modify the `Thing` type, and add a custom `ThingText` type, like so:

```
type ThingText struct {
    Title   string
    Body    string
}

type Thing struct {
    Id   string
    Text ThingText
}
```

This in itself isn't an issue, and I can modify the `Create` function like so:

```
thing := new(Thing)
thing.Id = dataMap["Id"].(string)
thing.Text.Title = dataMap["Title"].(string)
thing.Text.Body = dataMap["Body"].(string)
```

and the run the previous `curl` `POST` request with the `JSON` set to:

```
{"Id":"TestId","Title":"TestTitle","Title":"TestBody"}
```

and it returns with no error.

Once again I can `GET` the `Thing` URL and it returns:

```
{"d":{"Id":"TestId","Text":{"Title":"TestTitle","Body":"TestBody"}},"s":200}
```

Again, so far, so good.

Now, my question:

***how do I modify the `Create` function to allow me to `POST` complex `JSON` to it?***

For example, that last returned `JSON` string above includes `{"Id":"TestId","Text":{"Title":"TestTitle","Body":"TestBody"}}`. **I'd like to be able to `POST` *that exact `JSON`* to the endpoint and have the `Thing` created.**

I've followed the code back, and it seems that the `data` variable is of type `Context.RequestData()` from https://github.com/stretchr/goweb/context, and the internal `Map` seems to be of type [`Object.Map`](https://github.com/stretchr/stew/blob/master/objects/map.go#L20) from https://github.com/stretchr/stew/, described as ["a map[string]interface{} with additional helpful functionality."](https://github.com/stretchr/stew/blob/master/objects/map.go#L12) in particular, I noticed ["Supports dot syntax to set deep values."](https://github.com/stretchr/stew/blob/master/objects/map.go#L112)

I can't work out how I can set up the `thing.Text.Title = dataMap...` statement so that the correct `JSON` field is parsed into it. I can't seem to use anything other than `string` types in the `dataMap`, and if I try that `JSON` it gives an error similar to:

```
 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:59113: interface conversion: interface is nil, not string
```

Once again, sorry for the ridiculously long question. I really appreciate you reading, and any help you may have to offer. Thanks!

Comment: Now that you've posted the tl;dr question, post a question that we might read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [JSON package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) and [JSON and Go introduction](http://golang.org/doc/articles/json_and_go.html) describe, JSON data can be parsed either generically through interface{} / string maps or unmarshalling directly to the struct types.

The example code you linked to and you based your changes on seems to use the generic string-map approach, `dataMap := data.(map[string]interface{})`.

As your desired JSON data is an object in an object, it’s simply a map within a map.

So you should be able to

```
dataMap := data.(map[string]interface{})
subthingMap := dataMap["Text"].(map[string]interface{})
thing.Text.Title = subthingMap["Title"].(string)
thing.Text.Body = subthingMap["Body"].(string)
```

---

I’m not sure why that code uses casts and generic types over type-safe unmarshalling directly from JSON to struct types (abstraction I guess). Using the json packages unmarshalling to struct types would go something like

```
type ThingText struct {
    Title   string
    Body    string
}

type Thing struct {
    Id   string
    Text ThingText
}

…
decoder := json.NewDecoder(body)
var thingobj Thing
for {
    if err := decoder.Decode(&thingobj); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(thingobj)
}
```

where `body` is a `io.Reader` - in simple/most cases from `http.Response.Body`.

Comment: Thanks for that, the `subthingMap := dataMap["Text"].(map[string]interface{})` worked. Much appreciated!